# CUDA global memory deallocation issues in .NET

Tags: .net, interop, idisposable, cuda, garbage-collection

I have a class *(see example bellow)* which acts as a .NET wrapper for a CUDA memory structure,
allocated using cudaMalloc() and referenced using a member field of type IntPtr.
(The class uses DllImport of a native C DLL which wraps various CUDA functionality.)

The dispose methods checks if the pointer is IntPtr.Zero and if not calls cudaFree()
which successfully deallocates the memory (returns CUDA success)
and sets the pointer to IntPtr.Zero.

The finalize method calls the dispose method.

***The problem*** is, that if the finalize methods is called with out the dispose being called previously,
then the cudaFree() function sets an error code of "invalid device pointer".

I checked and the address the cudaFree() receives is the same address returned by the cudaMalloc() and no dispose() has been called previously.

When I add a explict call to dispose() the same address is successfully freed.

The only workaround I found was to not call the dispose method from the finalizer, however, this could cause a memory leak, if dispose() is not always called.

Any ideas why this happens? - I encountered the same issue with CUDA 2.2 and 2.3, under .NET 3.5 SP1 on Windows Vista 64bit + GeForce 8800 and on Windows XP 32bit + Quadro FX (not sure which number).

```
class CudaEntity : IDisposable
{
    private IntPtr dataPointer;

    public CudaEntity()
    {
        // Calls cudaMalloc() via DllImport,
        // receives error code and throws expection if not 0
        // assigns value to this.dataPointer
    }

    public Dispose()
    {
        if (this.dataPointer != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // Calls cudaFree() via DllImport,
            // receives error code and throws expection if not 0

            this.dataPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    ~CudaEntity()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

```
{
    // this code works
    var myEntity = new CudaEntity();
    myEntity.Dispose();
}
```

```
{
    // This code cause a "invalid device pointer"
    // error on finalizer's call to cudaFree()
    var myEntity = new CudaEntity();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't throw an exception if the free failed. MS guidelines suggest avoiding that.

Comment: I only added that to help debugging the problem,
however, for some unknown reason on one of the 2 PCs I worked on VS automatically treats the return code as an exception without me throwing one !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that finalizers are executed on the GC thread, CUDA resource allocated in one thread can't be used in another one. A snip from CUDA programming guide:

> Several host threads can execute
>   device code on the same device, but by
>   design, a host thread can execute
>   device code on only one device. As a
>   consequence, multiple host threads are
>   required to execute device code on
>   multiple devices. Also, any CUDA
>   resources created through the runtime
>   in one host thread cannot be used by
>   the runtime from another host thread.

Your best bet is to use the `using` statement, which ensures that the `Dispose()` method gets always called at the end of the 'protected' code block:

```
using(CudaEntity ent = new CudaEntity())
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks,
In most cases I do not use the CudaEntity in one block, so that solution won't help in most cases. I'll just have to inspect all the code to make sure the dispose() is always called when overwriting a CudaEntity or when an object containing CudaEntities is disposed.

Comment: +1.  I've found that when I need to use a CUDA wrapper object from multiple threads, the best bet is to keep a private Thread member in the wrapper class, and run all of the DllImport calls on that thread, so as to hide the thread-affinity details from client code.

Comment: Is it possible to dispatch during dispose? - I'm pretty sure the GC freezes all other threads unless using the server GC model.

Comment: How about adding a static dispose queue, then during finalize adding the pointer to the queue and on the next allocation or dispose, dispose everything on the queue?

Comment: Yes, that may work. But you'll need to route all CUDA calls through the allocating/freeing thread. It's kind of hackish approach, and way too defensive. What is the problem with releasing the resource once it's not needed?

Comment: I intend to do that, but I'd prefer to have a GC safety net, since I use many CUDA resources in many places and transfer them from place to place.

Comment: Another issue is unit testing - during unit testing a assert can cause a dispose to be skipped and each test is run from a different thread. I managed to implement a garbage stack that works even when unit testing.